# I am unable to create a react project for some reason

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, create-react-app, npx

When I run `npx create-react-app my-app`, I get:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn npm
npm ERR! path D:\ReactDemo
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn npm ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Mi PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-22T11_27_00_455Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to:

- Reinstall NodeJS
- Run: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && npm cache clean -f`
- Clear the system temp folder and set the environmental vars.
- Clear the npm cache folder etc.

Answer (score 1):

Update NPM:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Clear the cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Reinstall only globally:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm uninstall create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Restart your computer and start a CMD as administrator. Then you can try:

```
npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm
```

Or:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Or:

```
create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Thanks for Solution But not working .

The same error create

Comment: Whats your output for `npm -v`?

Comment: this output:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm -v
10.5.0

Comment: Please try to install a previous version: `npm i -g npm@10.2.4` and try to `npm i -g create-react-app` then `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution, but it didn't work. I'm still getting the same error.

I used, 
C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm -v
10.2.4